# upload an image from android app to the server

Tags: android, cordova

I try to upload an image from android app to the server. I am using HTML5 and phone gap. I am sending image from android app to remote server using WCF. when I try to upload using my app, it uploads a file but file is 0 size so nothing is in it. (my WCF works fine just I know problem is with my android app)

this is my upload code:

```
         function uploadPicture() {
        // Get URI of picture to upload  
        var img = document.getElementById('camera_image');
        var imageURI = img.src;

        if (!imageURI || (img.style.display == "none")) {

            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Take picture or select picture from library first.";
            return;
        }
        // Verify server has been entered  
        server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
        if (server) {
            // Specify transfer options    
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "file";
            options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            // Transfer picture to server
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
                document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload successful: " + r.bytesSent + " bytes uploaded.";
            }, function(error) { document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = " + error.code; },
                                                              options);

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
options.mimeType = "multipart/form-data";
```

And try to set some parameters. I am posting a sample code which is working for me:

```
var imageFile=$("#largeImage").attr('src');

                        if(imageFile=="")
                            alert("No image to upload.");
                        else{
                        var ft,options;
                        options = new FileUploadOptions();
                        options.fileKey = "profile_image";
                        options.fileName=name;
                        options.mimeType = "multipart/form-data";

                          params = {
                            val1: "some value",
                            val2: "some other value"
                          };
                          options.params = params;
                        ft = new FileTransfer();
                        ft.upload(imageFile, uploadUrl, success, fail, options);
                        }
                    }
```

I am using java servlet for handling the uploaded image.

Comment: I have used this code too, but still it is uploading image but it has 0 size.